# Al instalar Docker Desktop 4.24.0, aparece el error "Se denegó el acceso a la clave de Registro"

Tags: docker

Me sale el siguiente error:

> Instalation failed
>
> Component CommunityInstaller.AutoStartAction failed: Se denegó el acceso a la clave de Registro 'HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run'.
> en CommunityInstaller.InstallWorkflow.d__30.MoveNext()
>
> --- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la ubicación anterior donde se produjo la excepción ---
>
> en System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
> en CommunityInstaller.InstallWorkflow.d__23.MoveNext()

He probado de todo como desactivar los antivirus y dar los permisos con control total en la carpeta *run* pero aún así sigue saliendo cuando lo voy a instalar; confirmé que la cuenta tiene permisos de administrador también.

Comment: Que Windows y que versión, tu PC permite virtualización?

Comment: Es windows 10 Home y sí permite la virtualizacion y vi que lo tengo deshabilitado,puede ser ese el problema?

Comment: la añadi y no cambio nada

Comment: el WSL esta habilitado y corriendo?, seguí los pasos de la instalación de docker https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/windows-install/ y revisa que seas adminsitrador y que el windows este actualizado mínimo al 2019